# what is the main use of sql alternate key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am using sql server 2012. I want to just a use of **Alternate Key** in sql server that how can we use in our query and what is the actual logic of this. Can you give me suitable example of **Alternate Key**

Comment: hope helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736261/what-are-candidate-key-alternate-key-composite-key-in-sql

Comment: Ok @ahmedabdelqader , but can you give at-least an example with query

Comment: i read this:  http://www.jorriss.net/2015/04/09/why-you-absolutely-need-alternate-keys-a-unique-constraint-story/

Comment: @Naveen Soni Done. hope it helps.

Comment: If you don't know what an AK is, why do you want to "use" one? Keys are constraints. They tell you that a table is limited to certain values. They help you normalize to have simpler tables. In SQL they are associated with indexes for performance. They have no bearing on how you phrase a query unless you choose to make use of a certain index.

Comment: What do you know so far? What do you want "use" one for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming there is a table called `Student` with next structure

```
Create Table Student 
(
    StudentID int , 
    FirstName varchar(50), 
    LastName varchar(50), 
    CourseID int
)
```

`Candidate keys` are SID or FNAME+LAME

`Primary Key`: SID

`Alternate Key`:  FNAME+LAME

*now with some explanation*

**[Candidate Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key)** are those keys which is candidate for primary key of a table. simply all columns which full fill all the requirements of primary key.

**[Alternate Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Alternate_key)** After choosing primary key from those candidate keys, rest of candidate keys are known Alternate Key.

Answer (score 0):

Think about car.. it has a different unique numbers which can identify it, for example chassis number. That's one unique and can be used as a key to identify car.

Then each car has an engine that also has a unique number that can be used as ID of car as well. Then VIN, then such thing as license plate that some kind of temporary but still identify car and unique.

All these IDs are keys of car, all of them unique, all can be used as reference to one specific car.

Which is a primary key .. well it depends on you, it can be absolutely different one auto increment value that's unique just into your data source and not a worldwide, but all other numbers which I mentioned are definitely alternate keys for car record.

Same thing can be applied to many other entities, including people because we also have plenty of alternative identifiers such as passport number, driver license, SSN, phone number, etc.

Main question here if you really need to use some alternate key or not, because most of use cases in databases design don't require it at all. And sometimes it just make things more complicated.